# Seven-eight-six-five code six, one-oh-five north avenue

Tags: sound-effects, cliche

You guys know what I'm talking about. Any idea where this one originated? First place I heard it was in the loading screen for the game SWAT 3, so it kinda got drilled into my head after that.

Answer (score 3):

It is a part of the Hollywood Edge Premiere Edition sound effects library.

Comment: Which means, to further elaborate on the origins question, it's almost 100% guaranteed to have been custom-recorded for a Soundelux or Todd-AO show (either done by the Foley crew, or actually a field record from a real radio feed).  So it's likely that it was for a film (no idea which), and now has been immortalized in this HE library.

Answer (score 0):

[youtube]VebkRKfZoLI[/youtube]

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StockSoundEffects?from=Main.StockSoundEffect